# $C$ is weakly compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a Banach space, let $C\subset K\subset X$ such that $C$ is weakly closed and $K$ is weakly compact. Is $C$ then weakly compact ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Banach spaces and the weak topology. Closed subsets of compact spaces are compact in general.

Comment: @MaoWao: So post that as an answer (with a reference).  Then it can be selected by the OP.